# Using the ActiveRecord wrappers for a complicated query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

In my Rails app, I have the following PostgreSQL query to find the most commented story in the past week.

```
 last_week = Date.today() - 7
 most_commented_comments = Comment.find_by_sql("SELECT story_id, COUNT(*) AS total FROM comments WHERE created_at >= (CAST '#{last_week}' AS date) GROUP BY story_id ORDER BY 2 DESC LIMIT #{limit}")
```

I'm running into some cross-platform compatibility issues, especially with the `created_at >=...` clause and I'd like to make this a less brittle query overall. However, I can't seem to find a way to fit a complex query like this into the ActiveRecord wrappers given by Rails. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out a much better way.

```
most_commented_comments = Comment.where("created_at >= ?", Date.today - 7).select("story_id, COUNT(*) as total").group("story_id").order("2 DESC").limit(limit)
```

Comment: 1. i think you want `7.days`, 7 will mean 7 seconds? Or microseconds? :) Or you can do 1.week 2. What does `2 DESC` mean?

Comment: `2 desc` means ordering on the second column descending.

Comment: 7 appears to be working without the .days but I may add it just in case that stops working in the future.